# Combining Formulas add percent and roundup

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, combine

How can I combine the following formulas?

```
=f4*0.54
```

and

```
=roundup(d4,0)
```

In cell `D4` I have the formula `=f4*0.54`, which gives me our cost from an MSRP cost that I entered in cell `F4`, but the cost that shows in `D4` ends up being 137.11, I'd like it to just round up to 138.00.

[image]

Comment: Which formula is in which cell?

Comment: Combine them in what way?  Please show the original cell contents, describe what you want to accomplish with them, and what the contents should be when you're done.

Comment: When you say combine, are you looking for something like "=roundup(f4*0.54,0)" so that it multiplies f4 by 0.54 and rounds up without needing a new cell for the roundup formula?

Comment: I wish I could show snip, I'm no good at excel... so, in cell D4 I have the formula =f4*0.54, which gives me our cost from an msrp cost that I entered in cell f4, but the cost that shows in D4 ends up being 137.11, I'd like it to just round up to 138.00

Answer (score 1):

Like Andrew said, you can place the multiplication formula within the `=ROUNDUP` formula.

Something like`=ROUNDUP((F4*0.54),0)` would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, any time you reference a cell in a formula that has a formula too, you can instead insert the formula from that cell into the referencing formula.

That is, in this case: `=roundup(f4*0.54,0)`

Since the formula `=f4*0.54` is in `D4`, you replace the `D4` in `=roundup(D4,0)` with everything except the `=` (`f4*0.54`).